# How to use extension functions with Webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, momentjs

I'm trying to use `moment` with `moment-timer`, and it doesn't seem to be able to add the timer extension to the `moment` I have `require`d.

The top of my module looks like this:

```
var moment                = require('moment');

// this should add timer functions to moment.duration objects...
require('moment-timer');
```

I can see inside the `moment-timer` module that the code is set up to `require('moment')` on its own, so I assume that the `moment` object that's imported into `moment-timer` only exists within that module's scope. Because of this, I'm also assuming that my module's `require('moment')` imports a brand new one, which doesn't get extended. I'd rather not use globals for this (and I'm not sure it would even help). How can I get the extended `moment` into my module to use `duration.timer`?

### update

I've tried various things using the [imports-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/), so far to no avail. I will keep hacking at it and share any findings. What I tried (`webpack.config.js`):

```
module.exports: {
  // ...
  rules: [
    {
      test: require.resolve('moment-timer'),
      use: "imports-loader?define=>false,module=>false,moment"
    }
  ]
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried webpack `ProvidePlugin`?

Comment: Isn't that just importing something globally? The issue here is that the extension functions aren't working. Is there something in the ProvidePlugin I just don't know about?

Comment: I don't know if you get an error or not when including `moment-timer`. I assumed you got 'moment is not defined' error in somewhere. My guess is, `require('moment-timer')` cannot see your `moment` object.